# Trigger lock the table from Inserting data?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, locking

I am facing a problem please help
I written a **trigger to insert data** from testing table to main table
doubt is that if i insert data into that testing table should trigger locks the testing table because its in process of inserting into main table.

the main thing to clarify is that when multiple inserting takes place in testing table at a time does it allow to insert new records.

for example each inserting to main table takes 2-3 sec
for each second if it got more than 2 inserting how it works

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Locking means that you faced some use case where parallel work of several users leads to data inconsistency or other bad things and you're inventing locking to prevent it. Do you see such use case in your task? If so, think about locking.